vscode extension - Test CLI vs Your own Test Runner
I'm following the vscode
Testing Extensions docs. There seem to be 2 different configurations described.

The test CLI
Your own Runner

My questions:

Are these configurations mutually exclusive or can / should they be configured together.
Which use cases are better suited for the CLI vs the custom configuration?





They are not mutually exclusive. You can use both, choose one based on your needs:

Use Test CLI for straightforward integration with established tools

Use custom runner for unique or complex requirements






Test CLI: Best for simplicity and consistency with existing frameworks

Custom runner: Best for custom or specialized testing needs


It's how I use them, sometimes together

Laulee, thanks for the clarification. Do you have any examples of cases where a custom runner might be needed?

When my project uses a proprietary or custom-built testing framework that doesn’t have existing CLI tools or support in popular extensions or any situation CLI tools don't  provide adequate support or just not suit for the project
For example, when testing would involves complex setups in virtual environments, containers or custom hardware that needs specific preparation steps.
